# Using panda's groupby() how can I get several fuctions at once?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a basic dataframe (df) which has several transactions, it has a product id and a value, lets say it's the sales price, that's not fixed, so it would take the following form:

```
id | product_id | sale_price
---+------------+-------------
 1 |          1 |        100
 2 |          1 |        100
 3 |          2 |         98
 4 |          3 |         22
 5 |          1 |         95
   |        ... |        ...
```

So now I want to answer the questions: what is the average (mean), variation of the price for each product_id, and how many sales of each product_id are.

I'm doing as follows:

```
means  = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('item_id')['sale_price'].mean()).reset_index(level=0)
vars   = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('item_id')['sale_price'].var()).reset_index(level=0)
counts = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('item_id')['sale_price'].count()).reset_index(level=0)

result = pd.merge(means, vars, on='item_id')
result = pd.merge(result, counts, on='item_id')
```

And it does what I want, but I think it is terribly dumb, and there must be a better or "correct" way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby.agg` function, you can pass multiple aggregate function at the same time like so:

```
df.groupby('product_id')['sale_price'].agg(['mean', 'var', 'count'])
```

---

```
df.groupby('product_id')['sale_price'].agg(['mean', 'var', 'count']).reset_index()
​
#  product_id        mean        var    count
#0          1   98.333333   8.333333        3
#1          2   98.000000        NaN        1
#2          3   22.000000        NaN        1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but yes, this is a duplicate question. Maybe I have to learn more English so I can search for other expressions of the same question.